# Cannot export xml with UTF-16 - BCP SQL

Tags: sql, xml, bcp

```
DECLARE @XML NVARCHAR(MAX)  
DECLARE @bcp varchar(500)
DECLARE @FullPath varchar(500) 

SET @XML = N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>'+
            (
                    SELECT      'text1' as col1,
                                'text2' as col2
                    FOR XML PATH('col'), ROOT('record'), ELEMENTS XSINIL
            )
if ISNULL(OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..##TXML'),0) > 0 DROP TABLE ##TXML
CREATE TABLE ##TXML (XMLText NVARCHAR(MAX))
insert into ##TXML select @XML

set @FullPath =  'C:\Temp\test.xml'
set @bcp = 'bcp "SELECT XMLText from ##TXML" queryout "' + @FullPath + '" -T -w -S '+@@SERVERNAME
EXEC xp_cmdshell @bcp
DROP table ##TXML
```

Above is an example to export XML file with Encoding UTF-16.
The output was saying:

```
document labeled utf-16 but has utf-8 content
```

I've tried to use XML data type, but it will export without the header.

Could someone expert that can explain why I cannot have utf-16 content?

Thank you.

Comment: Se -f option (format) : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/create-a-format-file-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-unicode-native-format-to-import-or-export-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thank you, jdweng. I will practice with format file.
But, I decided to just have simple header: <?xml version="1.0"?>